# Magento - How to add custom block to Checkout success page

Tags: php, magento

I want to add some information to the checkout success page by adding a block to the page (without duplicating the template page and changing it).

I've looked at the downloadable module  and tried to copy it but that didn't work.
I have a custom module and I've tried to do this :

1) adding a block file to :
...\app\code\local\SHANI\MyModule\Block\checkout\Details.php

```
class SHANI_MyModule_Block_Checkout_Details extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success
{
}
```

2) adding a template file to :
...\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\mymodule\checkout\details.phtml

```
<?php
echo "test ffdagdf";
?>
```

3) adding the block to : ...\app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\mymodule.xml

```
<default>
</default>

....
....
....

<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="checkout.success">
        <block type="mymodule/checkout_success" name="mymodule.checkout.details" template="mymodule/checkout/details.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Does that the way to do it? What am I missing?

///////////////////////////////////////// update/////////////////////////////////////////

I've tried to change the mymodule.xml like Lrrr wrote but still no luck...

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="checkout.success">
            <block type="mymodule/checkout_details" name="mymodule.checkout.details" template="mymodule/checkout/details.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

any other ideas what is the problem?

I'm trying to do the same thing with the product view page and I was able to add a block to the "product.info.additional"
but not to the "product.info".

This is working:

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
           <block type="catalog/product_view" name="mymodule.saledetails" before="-" template="mymodule/product/details.phtml"/>
            <block type="mymodule/product_participant_list" name="mymodule.participants" before="-" template="mymodule/product/participant/list.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

But this isn't

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="mymodule.saledetails" before="-" template="mymodule/product/details.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <block type="mymodule/product_participant_list" name="mymodule.participants" before="-" template="mymodule/product/participant/list.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

I'm trying to move this block from  "product.info.additional"  to "product.info" because I want to show this block under 
the Quick Overview (in the default template) and not under the Details.
Why doesn't it work under the "product.info"?

Comment: I created a block on succes page, using same code pieces as You, but i used the mymodule/checkout_details block type, and I used the php tags at class SHANI_MyModule_Block_Checkout_Details. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

try to reference the content block in success page layout

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mymodule/checkout_success" name="mymodule.checkout.details" template="mymodule/checkout/details.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

instead checkout.success and you probably will need to call `$this->getChildHtml('yourblockname')` in template or add `output="toHtml"` to your block in layout

Comment: Can you explain how to call getChildHtml() or toHtml() on your block either in template or in layout?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. I changed my mymodule.xml file to : <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/checkout_success" name="mymodule.checkout.details" template="mymodule/checkout/details.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success> and it doesn't seam to show the text I've echoed in details.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print $this->getChildHtml('mymodule.checkout.details')
```

inside parent template without output="" in xml.

You can also check log for aditional info.

And to be sure it's now fault of Your block replace it with

```
type="core/template"
```

If Your module is

```
SHANI_MyModule_Block_Checkout_Details
```

then type should be

```
type="mymodule/checkout_details"
```

Comment: What is the "parent template"?

Answer (score 0):

`<block type="core/template" name="parent" template="parent.phtml>`

`<block type="core/template" name="child" template="child" />`

`</block>`

If You put in parent.phtml this `print $this->getChildHtml('child')` Magento should render child.phtml inside parent.phtml

As for Your other question... Some block render all blocks that are childs to them, but some renders only those blocks that are echo'ed inside their template. So 'product.info.additional'  can use `echo $this->getChildHtml()` and 'product.info' can use `echo $this->getChildHtml('block_name')`

Please provide me Your module config.xml